# Facing issue with JavaScript AJAX Call, CPU Memory Usage Spike

Tags: javascript, ajax, cpu-usage

While calling one ajax URL with the usage of JavaScript with some time interval like after every 2 minutes.

```
function tstat_run_request() {
  jQuery.get(`/ajax/url/table?page=${page}`, filter, function (e) {

    handler_interval = setInterval(function(){
            clearInterval(handler_interval)
            tstat_run_request()
        },120*1000)
  });
}
```

The above function is calling at page load, and after every 2 minutes, it's calling itself.

This is working fine as intended, But with some browser or some issue once in a week, my server is facing that it's running several times within seconds.

I have an Nginx server configured and checked incoming requests. With the above ajax URL, it's calling several times. And this is happening with some time only.

I have tested this with different types of browsers of desktop and mobile devices. But was not able to reproduce the issue.

This issue is happening once in a week or so, and I can see clearly spike in CPU up to 80%, (normally it is lower like 10%).

I was able to only reproduce this by commenting code of

```
clearInterval
```

in the above code.

Can any one help me with this out? How to detect and solve this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not 100% certain this will help, but I think `handler_interval` should be declared with `var`. Currently, it's a global variable (based on the code you posted).

Comment: Also since you clear the interval timer on the first iteration, you might as well just use `setTimeout()` anyway.

Comment: @Pointy, the code used the handler_interval variable above this function as well. should I declare it as var above the code?

Comment: If you use `setTimeout()` you won't need it at all, because `setTimeout()` only runs the callback once. Variables should *always* be declared explicitly however.